# Does Go have the standard functional primitives?

Tags: functional-programming, go

Does the standard library (or a popular agreed-upon library) let me map, filter, fold etc. over slices/maps?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No. Go's type system doesn't cater for the usual form of these primitives because it lacks generics.

See also [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/fb8fdf7eae5c55cf?pli=1) on golang-nuts.

Answer (score 0):

While Go does not have these primitives, it should be pointed out that the standard Go abstraction of a goroutine that you talk to through a channel will trivially give you entirely equivalent functionality in an asynchronous function.

Comment: @ross-light Good point.  Getting equivalent functionality is not entirely trivial.  But it is still doable in practice.  You can also use higher order functions.  But the lack of generics makes it hard to do any of this generically.

Comment: @RossLight "page not found" :(